# How do I upload files to the sharepoint shared documents folder (https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents) using Microsoft Graph Client

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

How do I upload files to the sharepoint shared documents folder using Microsoft Graph Client. I dont see any examples in the API documentation for the same. Is it possible to achieve the same via the Graph client API

Answer (score 0):

The following works

```
        Stream filecontents = new MemoryStream(filedata);
        await client.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(NameOfFile).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(filecontents);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on upload file to SharePoint Shared Folder, you can use the OneDrive SDK to implement your requirement(Or MS Graph OneDrive API).

If you insist on upload file to SharePoint but not OneDrive(although the OneDrive is a particular SharePoint site),you can see the following answer:

We can use the following API to operate the Documents Folder:
   Access the default drive (document library) for the given site.
    /sites/{site-id}/drive

```
Enumerate the drives (document libraries) under the site.
/sites/{site-id}/drives
```

You can try the following API to upload files:

```
PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
```

More infomation:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem_put_content

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/sharepoint

If above solution does not work on your side, then the result will be we cannot upload files to SharePoint Shared Documents folder directly by MS Graph Client now. Currently, Microsoft just support limited common feature for the following:List/Site/ListItem.

If the API doesn't work on your side, you may submit a feature request to the Product group:https://officespdev.uservoice.com/